# Express.js proper file not being sent as response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-sharing

I know this will be some stupid thing but I don't know why express.js is doing this.
So, I am sending a HTML file in a `GET` request

```js
const express = require("express");
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // console.log("Hello");
  // res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index2.html");
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port: " + PORT)
})
```

Now I was sending `index.html` instead of `index2.html` but it still sends the `index.html` file, even the `console.log` is not being printed.
Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express tests the routes one at a time **in order** until one matches.

> ```
> app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
> ```

Your very first route, which is the static route, matches!

---

If you want to prioritise your explicit end points over your static ones, then put the static route **last**.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you enabled serving static files for the whole application. It means that expess will route files from public folder at first, you have `index.html` that corresponds to `/`.

You can set a specific path for static something like that:

```js
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

More info here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html